# Output of Mask2FormerForUniversalSegmentation model is always 1

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

This training code is in mask2former's demo notebooks for fine-tuning and I run the demo successfully. Then I try it on my custom dataset and it doesn't work.
I am sure both my dataset and my dataloader are correct:

```
id2label = {0:"background",1:"text"}

from transformers import Mask2FormerImageProcessor, Mask2FormerForUniversalSegmentation
preprocessor = Mask2FormerImageProcessor(ignore_index=0, reduce_labels=False, do_resize=False, do_rescale=False, do_normalize=False)
model = Mask2FormerForUniversalSegmentation.from_pretrained("facebook/mask2former-swin-small-cityscapes-semantic", id2label=id2label, ignore_mismatched_sizes=True)

import torch
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model.to(device)

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=5e-5)

running_loss = 0.0
num_samples = 0
for epoch in range(20):
    print("Epoch:", epoch)
    model.train()
    for idx, batch in enumerate(tqdm(train_dataloader)):
        if batch == None:
            continue
        # Reset the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        # Forward pass
        #print(np.unique(batch["mask_labels"][0].numpy()))
        outputs = model(
            pixel_values=batch["pixel_values"].to(device),
            mask_labels=[labels.to(device) for labels in batch["mask_labels"]],
            class_labels=[labels.to(device) for labels in batch["class_labels"]],
        )

        # Backward propagation
        loss = outputs.loss
        loss.backward()

        batch_size = batch["pixel_values"].size(0)
        running_loss += loss.item()
        num_samples += batch_size

        if idx % 100 == 0:
            print("Loss:", running_loss/num_samples)

        # Optimization
        optimizer.step()

    model.eval()
    for idx, batch in enumerate(tqdm(test_dataloader)):
        if idx > 5:
            break

        pixel_values = batch["pixel_values"]
    
        # Forward pass
        with torch.no_grad():
            outputs = model(pixel_values=pixel_values.to(device))

        # get original images
        original_images = batch["original_images"]
        target_sizes = [(image.shape[0], image.shape[1]) for image in original_images]
        # predict segmentation maps
        predicted_segmentation_maps = preprocessor.post_process_semantic_segmentation(outputs,
                                                                                  target_sizes=target_sizes)
        segmentation_map = predicted_segmentation_maps[0].cpu().numpy()
        print(np.unique(segmentation_map))
        # get ground truth segmentation maps
        ground_truth_segmentation_maps = batch["original_segmentation_maps"]

        metric.add_batch(references=ground_truth_segmentation_maps, predictions=predicted_segmentation_maps)
  
    # NOTE this metric outputs a dict that also includes the mIoU per category as keys
    # so if you're interested, feel free to print them as well
    print("Mean IoU:", metric.compute(num_labels = len(id2label),reduce_labels=False,ignore_index = 255)['mean_iou'])
```

During the training, `print(np.unique(segmentation_map))`this step always prints [1] which means prediction of every pixel is always "text", Mean IoU is always 0.019564516938939475 and never changes, but loss keeps changing.

Another question is, `print("Mean IoU:", metric.compute(num_labels = len(id2label),reduce_labels=False,ignore_index = 255)['mean_iou'])` in this line, I try ignore_index = 0 and it warns:

```
  iou = total_area_intersect / total_area_union
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  acc = total_area_intersect / total_area_label
Mean IoU: 1.0
```

I want to know why the output never changes and why `ignore_index` can't be 0

Comment: You should check what the `ignore_index` parameter of `Mask2FormerImageProcessor` does. Some mask prediction datasets only predict positive masks, and have a certain index excluded from loss calculation. For your use, you are using `0` as the background class. Setting `ignore_index=0` might be throwing away all background pixels from the loss calculation, effectively only training the model on predicting `1`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is the ignore_index that cause the problem.